# Sound for me, but not for the 2nd Ubuntu account, why?

Tags: 16.04, sound, ubuntu-studio

I have sound playback for everything. But when going into my wife's account, there is none.
What could it be?

Thanks guys,

DPC

Comment: Can you create a third account and check the sound there?

Comment: Anwar, I tried both my daughter's and the Guest's accounts too, no sound either. But they were worse in the sense that they didn't show Built-in Audio Analog Stereo, on the lower half of the panel, as it shows on mine and my wife's. See the screenshot to see my Sound settings panel (Ubuntu Studio 16.04): https://sites.google.com/site/javierwebfolio/_/rsrc/1473340025827/temp/Sound%20settings_javier.jpg

Comment: Did you create your daughter's account after my comment? I wanted you to create a brand-new account

Comment: No, it was there already. But I just created a test account, and now the sound works!!! Should I do "sudo alsa force-reload"? If so, do I have to be in the affected accounts?

Comment: On the affected account run the command `rm -r ~/.config/pulse` logout and login to see what happens

Comment: Did that work good?

Comment: I just tried it. No changes when I use the command as is. If I use "sudo" then it says: rm: cannot remove 'home/user/.config/pulse': no such file or directory - :( - I also went back to the new test account I just created, only to find that it lost its sound too :(

Answer (score 1):

Did you go into System Settings > Sound and compare the audio profiles between your account and her account?

Here's mine for example:

[image: Sound]

If her settings are different and you cannot make them like your own update your question with the information.

If you set her settings on this screen the same as yours and she still has no sound, then it might be access rights / permissions to files as I presume you created the setup and her account was added second. This is beyond my pay grade but lots of smart people around here can hopefully solve that problem.

Comment: WinEunuuchs2Unix, they do look the same. This is how: 
Sound settings panel (Ubuntu Studio 16.04): https://sites.google.com/site/javierwebfolio/_/rsrc/1473340025827/temp/Sound%20settings_javier.jpg

If it is about right/permissions, how and where exactly do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Remove yourself from the audio group and reboot:
sudo vim /etc/group - 
The only thing that should be in the audio group is 'pulse' on most systems.
Thanks to Temujin, from UbuntuForums.org
Source: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2336570&p=13543062#post13543062